# Angular Custom Validation error message not working

Tags: html, angular, validation

Here my custom validation code:

```
<input type="date"  formControlName="Appli_DOB" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.Appli_DOB.touched && f.Appli_DOB.errors }">
<span *ngIf="f.Appli_DOB.hasError.DateofBirthValidation">Age Should be Greater Than 18 Years</span>
```

**Angular**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._MyregisterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Appli_DOB:['',Validators.required],
 validator: DateofBirthValidation('Appli_DOB')
});
```

**Custom Error Validation**

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
export function DateofBirthValidation(EnteredBirth:any){   
    return (group:FormGroup)=>{
        let _EnterBith=group.controls[EnteredBirth];
        if(_EnterBith.value!=""){   
        let timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() -new Date(_EnterBith.value).getTime());
        var age = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24))/365);
        console.log(age)
        if(age>=18){
            return true;
            _EnterBith.setErrors({DateofBirthValidation:true});
        }
        else{
         _EnterBith.setErrors({DateofBirthValidation:false});
        // _EnterBith.setErrors(null);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

It's working fine except for the error message. Why is the error not working?

Comment: Try adding a live demo to your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error in your code, you have set "return" statement, prior than setting the error. You need to set errors first then return true in your following code.

```
if(age>=18){
    return true;
    _EnterBith.setErrors({DateofBirthValidation:true});
}
```

the above statement should update to :-

```
if(age>=18){
    _EnterBith.setErrors({DateofBirthValidation:true});
    return true;
}
```